# Negate regex of validates_format_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

In my rails model I have some kind of template system. I want to make sure that users editing it do not make accidental mistakes so I use some simple validators.

They can use markers like `##user_id##` that will be replaced later. I want to make sure they do not enter something like `###user_id##` that contains too many `#`, so not any `###` (or `####`) must appear in the field.

```
class Template
  validates_format_of :text, :with => /##user_id##/, 
    :message => "##user_id## must be present"
  validates_format_of :text, :not_with => /###/, 
    :message => "Too many #"
end
```

Unfortunately there is no `:not_with` option ... is there any chance to solve it using a `:with`-regex or should I go a separate `validate` method?

I tried some negative look-ahead, but as there are (mostly) several `##` and only one `###` they always match one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this...

```
validates_format_of :text, :with => /(^|[^#])##user_id##($|[^#])/
```

**EDIT**: I copied acheong87's [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/Y3rzlKTCSI) examples with my regex.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `:without` option:

```
validates_format_of :text, :without => /###/, :message => "Too many #"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
    /^(.(?!###+user_id##|##user_id###+))*$/
```

Here's a live demo: http://rubular.com/r/SPwsyDlj0y.

In (more) English, it says,

> A string in which no character is followed by `###+user_id##` or `##user_id###+`.

Comment: This is some kind of query I tried before, but unfortunately it is not working with the `validates_format_of`